# Properly create Setup/MSI for Excel Application

Tags: vba, com, setup-deployment

I have an Excel 2016 solution that contains C# COM components as part of the deployment.  I am able to get the COM components to register OK.  However, there were a couple controls that were used, that existed on the development system that need to package as well.

TreeView and ListView controls are added in the references in the VBA IDE.  It referenced MSCOMCTL.OCX.  I have added this file as a dependency in the installer.  However, the installation fails to register the file.  I suspect that there may be additional dependencies I am missing?

Comment: You can't have that, MSCOMCTL.OCX isn't a redistributable library. Also it won't work in 64-bit VBA hosts.

Comment: So, is there a 64 bit version of the control available?  Or is there an alternative library I should be utilizing?

Comment: There isn't... it's a VB6 control library. Depending on what you're trying to do, consider making your UI in C# with modern tech (WinForms, WPF/XAML), and exposing a presenter and your model to VBA/COM; then if you follow modern UI patterns (not have all the logic in the form's code-behind) you can have VBA code providing/receiving data to/from the .NET UI.